# Node.js express send raw HTTP responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a legacy system that can return raw\plain HTTP responses as a string (text that contains all the required headers + body).

I would like to send this text directly without any parsing modifications for performance reasons.

So goal is to proxy received raw HTTP response.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = app.Router();

        router.get('request',()=>{
           const plainTextWithHeadersFromExternalSystem = `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                                   Date: Sun, 10 Oct 2010 23:26:07 GMT
                                   Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) mod_ssl/2.2.8 
                                   OpenSSL/0.9.8g
                                   Last-Modified: Sun, 26 Sep 2010 22:04:35 GMT
                                   ETag: "45b6-834-49130cc1182c0"
                                   Accept-Ranges: bytes
                                   Content-Length: 12
                                   Connection: close
                                   Content-Type: text/html

                                   Hello world!`;
           ... TODO: send text with headers and body as a response.
        });
```

It can be any content type, not only a plain text.

Any ideas whether it's possible to simply proxy it with the Node.js express lib?

Comment: `send this text directly without any parsing modifications for performance reasons.` What do you mean by **directly**? Would you like to literally put that stuff in response as a text or you actually want to process the text into response with exact structure ?

Comment: @JózefPodlecki yes, that is the goal. the properly formatted plain HTTP response is received from external systems. It would be great just to proxy it without express wrapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem myself and had to dive deeper into Node's core `http` and `net` modules to figure it out.

To skip the default HTTP response line (*e.g.* `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`) and all of the headers that Express/Node.js send, you can send your text directly through [the response's socket](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_socket).

```js
const responseMessage = `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 10 Oct 2010 23:26:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 13

Hello, World!

`

router.get('/request', (req, res) => {
  res.socket.end(responseMessage)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I think if you set [type](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.type) to `text/plain` and put string in [send](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.send) you can get exactly what you need

```js
router.get('request', (req, res) => {
  res.type('text/plain');
  res.send('text');
})
```

Comment: 3rd party can return any content type. I am not sure that res.send() will properly work if you are transferring as an argument raw HTTP response with all the headers.

Comment: Confirmed using this for returning mp3 (with the 'audio/mpeg' mime type)

Answer (score 1):

you can use following to set headers

```js
res.set({
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  'Content-Length': '123',
  // extra headers here
})
```

or you use 
`res.header(field, [value])`

complete code can be like this

```js
router.get('request', (req, res) => {
   res.set({
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      'Content-Length': '123',
      // extra headers here
   });
   res.send('Hello world!');
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the text already contains all the headers. I want just to resend it without parsing, and it looks like not possible.

Comment: so you want to do something like `res.send(plainTextWithHeadersFromExternalSystem)` ?

Comment: I dont know, how to do that.... those are part of response headers and you want it in body.  then you might need to map those key from headers to body and return.....